# ESP32 ESPNOW fails because of ESP_ERR_ESPNOW_IF

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I spent many hours on the ESP_ERR_ESPNOW_IF error that I can't explain, in my case.
I'm much likely missing the point...  :o

here are the essential chunks of code (the whole project is way too big to be posted)

- wifi init :

```
nvs_init();
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
esp_netif_t *ap_netif = esp_netif_create_default_wifi_ap();
esp_netif_t *sta_netif = esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();
wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg)); 
esp_err_t ret = esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA);
```

- espnow init :

```
ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_now_init() );
ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_now_register_send_cb(espnow_send_cb) );
ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_now_register_recv_cb(espnow_recv_cb) );
```

- add peer to list :

```
esp_now_peer_info_t *peer = malloc(sizeof(esp_now_peer_info_t));
peer->channel = 0;                       // Same channel as wifi softAP or station 
peer->ifidx = ESP_IF_WIFI_AP;      // ESP32 soft-AP interface 
peer->encrypt = false;                  // No LMK set
memcpy(peer->peer_addr, peer_mac_addr, ESP_NOW_ETH_ALEN);  // MAC address of new peer
ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_now_add_peer(peer) );                             // add peer to the list
```

---

When the esp32 runs, all goes well, until it tries to send a message to a peer. there comes the error ESP_ERR_ESPNOW_IF, which means that wifi interfaces of peer and espnow process are not the same.

But here are the tests I run to check these parameters..:

```
esp_now_peer_info_t peer_struct_temp;
esp_now_get_peer(&peer_debug_mac1, &peer_struct_temp); 
printf("channel : %d, IF : %d\n", peer_struct_temp.channel, peer_struct_temp.ifidx);

uint8_t protocol_bitmap_temp;
err = esp_wifi_get_protocol(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &protocol_bitmap_temp);
printf("err : %d, interface STA, bitmap : %d\n", err, protocol_bitmap_temp);

err = esp_wifi_get_protocol(ESP_IF_WIFI_AP, &protocol_bitmap_temp);
printf("err : %d, interface AP, bitmap : %d\n", err, protocol_bitmap_temp);
```

And the console prints I get :

```
espnow_send FAILED, err : ESP_ERR_ESPNOW_IF
channel : 0, IF : 1
err : 0, interface STA, bitmap : 7
err : 0, interface AP, bitmap : 7
```

Which means, I believe, that :

-peer is correctly set in ESP_IF_WIFI_AP ( = 1)

-both ESP_IF_WIFI_STA and ESP_IF_WIFI_AP are created (otherwise, err would not be equal to ESP_OK)

...??

If someone has got a hint, a suggestion, an idea... it would be of a great help.
Thank you all :)

Comment: Did you try the [example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/wifi/espnow) that come with ESP-IDF? I did a range test using ESP-Now with a pair of ESP-01(ESP8266) more than a year ago, and wrote [my codes](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/05/esp-01-range-test-with-esp-now-protocol/) in Arduino framework (but calling all the underneath ESP-IDF functions), the code is much abstract and cleaner than the ESP-IDF example for understanding how the ESP-Now works, I also used a pre-set MAC addr to save the scanning time for getting peer  MAC addresses.

Comment: Yes, and I got it working without any problem. I also built several custom applications with espnow in it, and it worked seamlessly. But as you said, the espnow protocol (and especially the example) are not crystal clear :) That's why I probably have forgotten something, but I can't see where..?